# Run Emacs in GUI mode without X over SSH

Tags: ssh, gui-emacs, x11

With Emacs 26.1 installed on a Linux RedHat flavour without X, I want to run Emacs GUI over an SSH connection with X11 forwarding and Xming server on client. Since there is no X on the machine, Emacs starts in text mode. I know that "emacs -nw" forces Emacs in text mode, but how to force GUI?

Comment: I don't want to install Emacs for Windows and run emacs server on target linux machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs will start "in GUI mode" automatically when possible.  There are basically 2 conditions that need to be satisfied:

- You must use an Emacs built with GUI support.
- There must be an Xserver it can connect to, which is indicated by the usual `$DISPLAY` environment variable.

So make sure your Emacs was built with GUI support, and make sure you launch it from a shell where `$DISPLAY` is set properly.

Comment: After verifying the system-configuration-options variable I have confirmed that my emacs is compiled with X11 support. $DISPLAY variable was not properly set since xauth was missing.